# Python: RuntimeError: invalid slot offset when importing a module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting above error when trying to import ssl module. 
In fact, the error showed up during the build and _ssl module was added to the failed module list.
 However, the compilation and link went well.

There was no error on compilation and link phases, only some warnings. However, during Python build, there is an import phase right after the link, which shows the same error as stated.

```
building '_ssl' extension 
xlc_r -DNDEBUG -O -IInclude -I. -I/usr/local/include -c /aix/Modules/_ssl.c -o build/temp.aix-6.1-3.3/aix/Modules/_ssl.o
 "/aix/Modules/_ssl.c", line 262.17: 1506-196 (W) Initialization between types "void*" and "struct _object*(*)(struct {...}*)" is not allowed.
 /aix/Modules/ld_so_aix xlc_r -bI:/aix/Modules/python.exp build/temp.aix-6.1-3.3/aix/Modules/_ssl.o -L/usr/local/lib -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.aix-6.1-3.3/_ssl.so
 ld: 0711-224 WARNING: Duplicate symbol: .bcopy 
ld: 0711-224 WARNING: Duplicate symbol: .memcpy 
ld: 0711-224 WARNING: Duplicate symbol: .memmove 
ld: 0711-345 Use the -bloadmap or -bnoquiet option to obtain more information. 
*** WARNING: importing extension "_ssl" failed with build/lib.aix-6.1-3.3/_ssl.so: <class 'RuntimeError'>: invalid slot offset: <traceback object at 0x3017e9e0>
```

Could anyone shed some lights on how to get it work?

Env:
Python: 3.3.2 
OpenSSL: 0.9.8y (also tried 0.9.7) 
OS: AIX 6.1 (also tried on HPUX_1131_IA)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is solved, there are different versions of SSL, and the error happened when the wrong one was chosen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference:

This is solved, there are different versions of SSL, and the error happened when the wrong one was chosen and the setup.py was messed up.